# Does $\sin z$ assumes all complex numbers? Or all except $i$ & $-i$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Q. 1 Let $f(z) = \sin z$, $z \in C$. Then $f(z)$

a. is bounded in the complex plane

b. assumes all complex number

c. assumes all complex numbers except $i$

d. assumes all complex numbers except $i$ & $-$i.

Q.2 If $f(z) = \tan z$, then would the answer be same?

Q.3 Also why $\sin z$ is not bounded in complex plane?

Comment: Do you know Picard's theorem?

Comment: @Tobias Yes using Picard's we are down to option b or c. Is there any other result that will help narrow down the answer?

Comment: Just note that $\rm{sin}(-z) = -\rm{sin}(z)$.

Comment: Can you explain in more details? Did not quite understand.

Comment: The above observation implies that if some $x$ is not in the image of $\rm{sin}$ then $-x$ is also not in the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q3. $\sin(z)$ is entire.

Also $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2i}$.

If you try to solve $\sin(z)=y$ you get

$$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=y$$

This is quadratic equation in $e^{iz}$ and has solutions in $z$ as long as $e^{iz} \neq 0$. Solve it and this will answer Q1,Q3.

For Q2, the equation

$$\tan(z)=y \Leftrightarrow \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}=y$$
is again quadratic, solve it.

Comment: $\sin z=\displaystyle\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$.

Comment: When does $e^{iz}=0$?

Comment: @julien Never, but potentially a quadratic equation could have $0$ as a root... Anyhow this is a very particular quadratic ;)

Comment: This is what I came up with. 
Take e^iz=t, then we get this quadratic equation 

t^2-2iyt-1=0

Solving it, we get t = iy +- Sqrt(1-y^2)

i.e. e^iz = iy +- Sqrt(1-y^2)

I got lost at this step. How to proceed further?

Comment: @John the equation $e^{iz}=w$ always has solutions if $w \neq 0$. You can see this by writing $z=a+bi$ and $w$ in Polar coordinates...

Comment: @N.S. I'm not getting it exactly. Can you please share the solution?

Comment: @John Write whatever what you got in Polar coordinates. You don't need to write it, just use the fact that that number can be written... Then solve $e^{iz}=R(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta) \,.$

Comment: You don't need to find the solution explicitelly just to see that it exists...

Comment: @N.S. This is what I got. e^iz = sqrt(1-y^2) +- iy = re^iθ. (0 <= θ < 2PI) . Then Taking logs, we get one root as z = θ - i log r. The other root would be negative of that i.e. -θ + i log r. What next?

Comment: @John You just showed that $\sin(z)=y$ has solution for all $y$ ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. So it assumes all the complex numbers. Thanks N.S.

Comment: I solved the same for tan z. I got this. e^iz = (1 + iy)/sqrt(1+y^2). It does not have solution if y = i or -i . So Tan Z assumes all values except i & -i. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

On Q2, the sine function is entire and nonconstant. By Liouville's theorem, it must be unbounded.   This rules out a on Q1.  Alternative d bites the dust since the range of an entire function is either the whole complex plane or the complex plane less one point (Picard's Theorem).  Can you decide between b and  c?

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, Tobias has given a good hint. For Q3, see that $$\operatorname{sin}(-ix) = - i \operatorname{sh}(x)$$