# Showing that $f(z) = \left(z_1 - \sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)\left(z_2 - \sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)$ has a zero in $B(0,1/n)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find a way to show that $$f(z) = \left(z_1 - \sin\left(\tfrac{1}{z}\right)\right)\left(z_2 - \sin\left(\tfrac{1}{z}\right)\right)$$ (with $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$) has a zero in the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to use the definition of an entire function but I'm afraid this might not be entire because it is undefined at $z = 0$ and this approach is wrong. Is there another way for me to show that this is true (or false)?

Comment: $\sin(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, and so has your function.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I just realized that. Is there a way for me to be able to show that it has zeroes in B(0,1/n) no matter the value of the natural number n? Sorry, I've been working on this problem for weeks but still no progress.

Comment: I would suggest that you update your question (and the title) to what you *actually* want to know.

Comment: @MartinR Just changed it, I'm really sorry and thank you for replying

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. “$f(z)$ has its zeros in the ball of radius $1/n$ for all $n$” would mean that $f$ has no zeros at all. Or do you mean “for every integer $n$, $f(z)$ has zeros in the ball of radius $1/n$”?

Comment: @MartinR I meant the latter, thank you for pointing that our, English isn't my first language

Comment: @GabRomero I edited your question. Is this what you meant? What are $z_1$ and $z_2$?

Comment: @Gary Yes, that is what I mean and z1 and z2 are complex numbers. I also edited my question accordingly. Thank you so much for the help, and I am so sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: (1) See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301242/does-sin-z-assumes-all-complex-numbers-or-all-except-i-i) showing that $\sin \zeta$ takes all complex values.  Thus for any $u \in \mathbb C$, $u - \sin \zeta = 0$ has a solution.  


(2) It therefore has infinitely many solutions of form $\zeta + 2n\pi$.  


Hopefully you can work your problem from here.

Comment: @WADon Thank you so much for this. My only problem is won't (1) depend on $\sin \zeta$ being entire based on the answer to that question you linked? so it might not apply to $sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ because it is not entire? Sorry!

Comment: The referenced article shows that $\sin \zeta$ takes all values without needing to use the fact that it is entire;  but if $\sin \zeta$ takes all values then so does $\sin 1/z$.  To see this, for any $u$ we can always obtain $\zeta $ such that $\sin \zeta = u$.  We can exclude $\zeta = 0$ by choosing instead $\zeta = 2\pi$.  Then put $z = 1/\zeta$ and $\sin (1/z) = \sin(\zeta) = u$.